# Erro ao instalar o Rails no Linux Mint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby, mint

Ao executar o sudo gem install rails, recebi essa mensagem de erro:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.7.0.1/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170305-1916-hney9w.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Verifiquei a libxml2, está instalada

Comment: Tente instalar [esse pacote aqui](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/zlib1g-dev).

Answer (score -1):

De uma olhada neste script:

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/c5fce7359bed8f93a63d017f6e764d614a9967f8/scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu

O RVM usa esse script para instalar as dependências necessárias para instalar as gems mais comuns no ubuntu, por consequência no mint.

Instalando os pacotes ai listados vai resolver seu problema.